# Why is the last table row not following text-align center CSS?

Tags: html, css, html-table, text-align

On this page https://www.bridgecitychrysler.com/book-service/, under the "Hours of Operation" section, the last table element, (Sun Closed), is not aligning centre in its table row, even though the other two items are. I believe the CSS is targeting them all the same, so I have no idea why it isn't working solely on the last row.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: If you can share a screenshot of how you want it to display, then it would help. I see that you are overriding the table's default display to `flex` which causes unnecessary alignment issues. Keep the table's default behavior if possible, and you can simply alter the table's `<th>` and `<td>` to render it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not aligning because of the word "closed". If you change the "closed" to "9:00 AM - 5:00 PM" as Saturday, You will get the Sunday one aligned.
[image: Edited Image]

I can't exactly tell why it's like that because I couldn't find the css code, but it's probably not aligned correctly in the css.